# Can Android library (jar/aar) be used for iOS in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I know [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/) I can add Android library (jar/aar) to Xamarin project. If I compile this project for iOS, will it work ? I read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934138/using-java-library-in-ios-project/) it is not possible because of iOS do not have jvm. Is this situation same for Xamarin ?

Comment: Java code won't run on iOS. Code needs to be compiled to native code. Xamarin will not magically convert bytecode to arm64, just as you couldn't link an iOS Framework into a Xamarin project and expect it to run on an Android device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this situation same for Xamarin?

Yes, you can't add jar to Xamarin.Ios.

Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Ios is just a wrapper for Native Android or Ios.

You can use c# to code Xamarin.Android project, and run the Xamarin.Android project on a Android device,these all based on [Android Callable Wrappers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/architecture#android-callable-wrappers) and [Managed Callable Wrappers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/architecture#managed-callable-wrappers).